Transform transactional text data to columns in Excel or Google Sheets
I have a table of 40,000+ historical performance rating records that I need to pivot into columns using either excel or google sheets. In SQL I'd write a case statement but this info isn't in my data warehouse.



ID
Cycle
Rating




A
1
ME


A
2
MM


B
1
EE


B
2
ME



I'd like the table to look like this



ID
Cycle 1
Cycle 2




A
ME
MM


B
EE
ME



I tried pivot tables but they are intended for aggregation. I tried Query in Google Sheets but couldn't figure it out. I suppose I could filter and copy/paste but I'm hoping for a more programmatic solution.

Excel and Google Sheets are two separate and distinct products, with significant differences in use and functionality. Please use the tag ONLY for the product you're actually using. Tag spamming is a good way to quickly get your question downvoted and closed here. Tags have relevance and meaning, and should be used properly. For more information about the use of tags, see the [help].

Are there exactly two cycles?

@ike there are varying cycles. Some folks have 1 some have 10.

In Google Sheets you can indeed use the QUERY function as follows:
=LET(data, HSTACK(A1:A5, ARRAYFORMULA(B1&" "&B1:B5), C1:C5), QUERY(data, "select Col1, min(Col3) group by Col1 pivot Col2", 1))
The LET part, before the actual query, is just there to prepend the word "Cycle" to the cycle numbers in the headers. Since you need to use an aggregate function, I've chosen (rather arbitrarily1) min().

1 This assumes that there aren't multiples row with identical ID and cycle but different rating, as in your example data.

EDIT - If you want to use whole columns as ranges (e.g. A1:A), you need to add the condition where A is not null to the query; otherwise there would be an empty column and an empty row. The formula becomes:
=LET(data, HSTACK(A1:A, ARRAYFORMULA(B1&" "&B1:B), C1:C), QUERY(data, "select Col1, min(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 1))
References

QUERY
LET
HSTACK


In Excel you can use pivot the table using Power Query:

let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", type text}, {"Cycle", Int64.Type}, {"Rating", type text}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Cycle", type text}}), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Cycle", type text}})[Cycle]), "Cycle", "Rating")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"


With Excel 365 you can use this formula:
=LET(data,SORT(Table1,{1,2}),
     uniqueIDs,UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(data,1)),
     transposedRatings,WRAPROWS(CHOOSECOLS(data,3),2),
     HSTACK(uniqueIDs,transposedRatings))

As it is not clear: a sort is first applied to the data, then WRAPROWS creates the transposed data.
ASSUMPTION: there are exactly 2 ratings per each ID!

